# Magento 2 Customers can't login and add product to cart

Tags: magento2, login, addtocart

The customers can't login, Magento return a 302 found response

[image: Error trying to login]

The admin can login without problems.

And I can't add products to cart, Magento returns a 302 found response.

I already do: 
**Clean cache** "magento cache:clean" 
**Flush cache** "magento cache:flush" 
**Compile** "magento setup:di:compile" 
**Reindex** "magento indexer:reindex"

I try to create a new customer and it works, the customer was created without problems, but when I try to add a product isn't work.

Comment: Don't try to use `localhost` as a Top Level Domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Don't try to use `localhost` as Top Level Domain(TLD)**. That may cause your current issues: can't login and add product to cart. We can choose some domains like: `mage.loc`, `mysite.loc`,.. If you're are using Apache on Windows, you can follow this guide: http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache_vhosts.php to create a Virtual host.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, I was debugging the Magento 2 code and the problem i found is, the formKey is allways diferent. How can i fix that.

Comment: I faced the same problem while using `localhost` as domain name. After changing the domain it is working.