# Add to cart Ajax response 302 in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, ajax

I am facing some **problem regarding product add to cart**. Whenever i am trying to **add any configurable** of simple product to **my cart**. It is not getting added to cart. Also When i checked in console, I saw an ajax problem in that. **Ajax giving 302 error. When I am adding any product to cart.**

Please anyone help me to resolve it.

Comment: Check magento log file for error.

Answer (score 4):

I have changed unsecure and secure url  **localhost** to **127.0.0.1** in table **core_config_data** and its working fine

Hope this will help someone!

Comment: You've saved my life man. Tks!

Answer (score 3):

Seem that you tried to use **`localhost` as Top Level Domain (TLD)**. Try to use other domains like `magen.loc`, `magen2.loc`, etc.

Read more: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145192/33057

Comment: I don't think that its a domain problem. Because I setup the magento on my test server also. And again the problem not resolved. If the problem cause by `Localhost` , then it should work on my test server. But its not working there also.

Comment: I am getting ajax response **302 Found** while add to cart. This is the main problem. Otherwise customer login and other functions are working well. Please tell me why i am getting 302 response and how to resolve this.

Comment: Try to clear your Magento cache, Browser cache and cookie!

Comment: Tried to deploy static content, cache clean . Still not working. :(

Comment: It just miiiight be that you can have to put a tld (an 'extension', a .com, .io, .ru, .whatever ) in your URL. So localhost won't work, and magento2 didn't work for me. But magento2.io did.