# Can not login with customer emai1 in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, login, customer-account

I am getting below error in my log file when try to login.

```
 main.CRITICAL: No such entity with customerId =  [] []
```

Tried below solution that didn't work.

[Magento 2 - Moving site - 'No such entity'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102739/magento-2-moving-site-no-such-entity)

Comment: Can you please tell me status code from console when you login? It will display in loginpost request.

Comment: @RohanHapani, yes the status code is 302 not found

Comment: Try this. It may be useful : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/145192/51810

Comment: @RohanHapani, No i am not working in localhost, we are using in dev site, which has domain.

Comment: I have checked in other site, where the status code is 302 but the customer is logged in,

Comment: Did you try by other customer credential?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86096/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: @RohanHapani, yes record is there in table

Comment: @RohanHapani, can you check it please?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to check that.

Comment: can you look into it please?

Comment: Yes sure. I will give you update.

Comment: @RohanHapani, could you check it?

Comment: @RohanHapani, can you please update to this issue?