# Change of customer login error message magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I am trying login with invalid customer email address, that doesn't exist in magento db.

When i try to login with that email. I am getting error like

```
"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."
```

even though account doesn't exist.

Shall we show as "Customer Doesn't Exist!!!." instead of above error.

I have used the plugin like below

```
 public function afterExecute(\Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost $subject, $result) 
{       
    $storeScope = \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE;        
    if ($subject->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $login = $subject->getRequest()->getPost('login');

        if (!empty($login['username']) && !empty($login['password'])) {

            $customerId = $this->getCustomer(trim($login['username']));
            if(isset($customerId) && $customerId!= ''){
                $currentCustomer = $this->getcurrentcustomer($customerId);                                  
                try {
                    return $result;     
                }
                catch (\Exception $e)
                {
                    $message = "Invalid user Credentials.";
                    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
                    $this->session->setUsername($login['username']);
                    $this->responseHttp->setRedirect('customer/account/login');

                }
            }else{
                $message = "The email address not Exist!";
                $this->messageManager->addError($message);
                $result->setPath('customer/account/login');                         
                return $result;                             
            }

        }            
    }

}

public function getCustomer($email)
{
    try{
        $websiteID = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->create()->setWebsiteId($websiteID)->loadByEmail($email);
        $userId = $customer->getId();           
        return $userId;
    }catch (\Exception $e){

        return false;
    }
}
```

The message is showing but, It is also showing the other message also, How can we hide that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Showing message "**Customer Doesn't Exist!**" in case of customer does not exist will be a security issue.
Any attacker may enter a random email and will get verified that the account exists in the Magento system or not, this may lead to a brute force attack.

Comment: hi @Milind , Okay i got it. can you help me on this please, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250848/can-not-login-with-customer-emai1-in-magento2

Comment: hi @Milind, can we remove the other message please?

Comment: Need to check and will update you

Comment: hi @Milind, ok sure

Comment: hi @Milind, could you check it?